# Different execution plan in windows and Linux for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, sql-execution-plan, postgresql-12

I have recently deployed PostgreSQL database on Linux server.
One of the stored procedure is taking around 3 to 4 seconds to fetch the result. Previously i was deployed PostgreSQL database to windows server and the same stored procedure fetching result within second. I have checked execution plan in both the cases. 
It is almost same but Linux execution plan contains below extra detail.

```
    JIT:
  Functions: 171
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 26.548 ms, Inlining 8.198 ms, Optimization 2052.958 ms, Emission 1241.730 ms, Total 3329.434 ms
```

Let me know if you have any idea for above detail and have any root cause of slowness issue.

Comment: Are networks exactly alike, or you running query on the server?

Comment: both are running in different server in the same data center.

Comment: Loads of things it could be (machine specs, disk speeds, postgres version, configuration etc) but in this case, based on the "JIT:" in your question, I'd guess that [JIT compilation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/jit-reason.html) is enabled on the linux box and not on windows.

Comment: Try disabling JIT on the Linux system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like JIT is doing you more harm than good on Linux, so turn it off, by for example putting `jit=off` in postgresql.conf file.

Your Windows version probably didn't come with JIT in the first place.  The EnterpriseDB installer for Windows didn't include it, anyway.  So even though the parameter `jit` shows as `on`, it doesn't do anything as there is nothing there to turn on.